# how can I publish my log approximation formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, constructive-mathematics

I've successfully found out a formula which can give log value of any base till 4-5 places after decimal I want to know whether it can get published because I've seen some journals which have published approximation of log for different basses.but my formula can generate log value for all positive numbers. I need some help?

Comment: People have been computing logarithms for 400 years. The chances of someone finding a formula that does something no one else has done before are pretty close to zero. The chances of someone who has never published a paper before finding a formula that does something no one else has done before are exactly zero. A better idea would be to post your formula here, with a request that someone tell you how long it has been known.

Comment: Sure there are many formulas for approximation. I've seen and searched many but my formula has never been published c there is formula for x<-1 and also for -1<x<1 and there are many scientists who have been giving formulas but my formula is never been published.

Answer (score 1):

ArXiv.org is the webpage for sharing.